# Does a Windows host correctly interpret dnsmasq parameters?

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server, dnsmasq, dhcp-option

I have a network of Windows 10 machines served (DNS and DHCP) by a `dnsmasq` instance on a Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 15.10, `dnsmasq` 2.75). The setup basically works (`dnsmasq` provides addresses and manages DNS requests correctly) except for one specific case.

I wanted to provide a specific DNS server to one particular machine. I used the `tag` option in `dnsmasq`:

```
# open zone
dhcp-host=84:3a:4b:20:94:f0,set:open

# DNS for everyone = OpenDNS
dhcp-option-force=option:dns-server,208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220
# DNS for open = Google
dhcp-option-force=tag:open,option:dns-server,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

Upon `ipconfig /renew` on the client, the correct options are sent by `dnsmasq`:

```
root@srv ~# dnsmasq -d
dnsmasq: started, version 2.75 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
dnsmasq: reading /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq: using nameserver 192.168.0.254#53
dnsmasq-dhcp: DHCP, IP range 10.10.10.20 -- 10.10.10.100, lease time 5d
dnsmasq: cleared cache
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 available DHCP range: 10.10.10.20 -- 10.10.10.100
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 vendor class: MSFT 5.0
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 client provides name: helloworld.example.com
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 DHCPREQUEST(lan0) 10.10.10.21 84:3a:4b:20:94:f0
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 tags: open, known, lan0
dnsmasq-dhcp: Ignoring domain example.com for DHCP host name helloworld
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 DHCPACK(lan0) 10.10.10.21 84:3a:4b:20:94:f0 helloworld
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 requested options: 1:netmask, 3:router, 6:dns-server, 15:domain-name,
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 requested options: 31:router-discovery, 33:static-route, 43:vendor-encap,
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 requested options: 44:netbios-ns, 46:netbios-nodetype, 47:netbios-scope,
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 requested options: 121:classless-static-route, 249, 252
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 next server: 10.10.10.254
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  1 option: 53 message-type  5
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 54 server-identifier  10.10.10.254
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 51 lease-time  5d
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 58 T1  2d8h23m1s
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 59 T2  4d5h23m1s
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option:  1 netmask  255.255.255.0
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 28 broadcast  10.10.10.255
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option:  3 router  10.10.10.254
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 15 domain-name  testlab
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size: 18 option: 81 FQDN  03:ff:ff:6c:77:35:79:6f:70:32:64:73:79:2e...
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  8 option:  6 dns-server  8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  1 option: 46 netbios-nodetype  08
dnsmasq-dhcp: 342453732 sent size:  4 option: 44 netbios-ns  10.10.10.254
```

So the client is given the IP `10.10.10.21` (I changed it during the tests and the correct one is assigned every time, for every change - so the response to the request is correctly interpreted by the client) and, among others, the specific DNS servers.

Everything looks good from the `dnsmasq`side.

On the client I get

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : testlab
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 84-3A-4B-20-94-F0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::74d6:d6c:a5cc:54c7%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.21(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : samedi 2 avril 2016 15:59:55
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : jeudi 7 avril 2016 16:03:15
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 75774539
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-87-7B-B4-3C-97-0E-67-52-6C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.254
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I checked with Wireshark on the client the received traffic. In the `DHCP ACK` packet (the one recived from the DHCP server) the option is correct (so it was no stripped on the way or something like this):

[image]

The IP is OK but the DNS server is not correct: it defaults to the DHCP server - it looks like the received option is not correctly interpreted (?)

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem: **my DNS settings on the client were static**. The IP was assigned via DHCP.

This is not normal and what brought me to check that is that I have had the same issue of the DNS switching to a static IP before - when going between my home and work network.

Again - this is not a normal situation and if I find out what causes the DNS to switch to a static IP I will update this answer.